# Output formatting in Python: replacing %s with the defined variable

Tags: python

How do I replace %s with a defined/non-empty variable string? Or rather what is the Pythonic or syntactic sugar for doing so?

Example:

```
# Replace %s with the value if defined by either vehicle.get('car') or vehicle.get('truck')
# Assumes only one of these values can be empty at any given time
# The get function operates like http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get
logging.error("Found duplicate entry with %s", vehicle.get('car') or vehicle.get('truck'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
'Found duplicate entry with %s' % (vehicle.get('car') or vehicle.get('truck'))
```

This will replace the `'%s'` with the non-empty string (assuming only one is non-empty). If both contain text, it will be replaced with the output of `vehicle.get('car')`

You could also use this type of string formatting:

```
'Found duplicate entry with {0}'.format(vehicle.get('car') or vehicle.get('truck'))
```

This will return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
logging.error("Found duplicate entry with %s" % (vehicle.get('car') or vehicle.get('truck')))
```

Or if `truck` is also empty, you can return a default value:

```
logging.error("Found duplicate entry with %s" % (vehicle.get('car') or vehicle.get('truck', 'default')))
```